# Convert year month to different format

Tags: bash, date

I have year and month in the format `YYMM` and I want to convert them to `YYYY Month` format. The year is always 2000 and later. So for example;

- `1908` becomes `2019 Aug`
- `1904` becomes `2019 Apr`
- `2012` becomes `2020 Dec`
- `2111` becomes `2021 Nov`

I have written up a script shown below:

```bash
rand=(1908 1904 2012 2001 2111)
months=(Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec)
for i in $rand
do
    echo ${i:2:2}
    if [ ${i:2:2} -lt 1 ] || [ ${i:2:2} -gt 12 ]
        then echo "Month: ${i:2:2}. Last 2 values must be a month between 01 and 12."
    fi

    printf "20${i:0:2} ${months[${i:2:2}]}"
done
```

But, I get some errors.

```
line 13: 08: value too great for base (error token is "08")
```

I think the single digit months with padded zero is an issue in some places but works in other.

Not sure how to make Bash understand that `08` is just `8`. I tried to change `${i:2:2}` to `$((i:2:2))`. But, that doesn't work.

```
line 7: i:2:2: syntax error in expression (error token is ":2:2")
```

Comment: That looks more like `zsh` syntax than `bash` syntax. `zsh` has a builtin interface to `strptime()` and `strftime()` though (the `strftime` builtin in the `zsh/datetime` module), so you wouldn't need to do it by hand like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`08` is interpreted as an invalid octal number. It's octal since it starts with zero, it's invalid because it contains `8`.   It does this because you're using this substring as a  number in an arithmetic context (an integer comparison). You would have the same issue with `09` but not with `07` or lower numbers.

The following script does the calculation using the date 2000-01-01 plus the `YY` bit of the number as a year. It then adds the rest of the string as some number of months, and subtracts one day. This calculation lands on the last day of the month that the `YYMM` code refers to.  With `%Y %b`, the year and month is outputted in `YYYY Mon` format.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

datecodes=(1908 1904 2012 2001 2111)

for datecode in "${datecodes[@]}"; do
        printf -v thedate '2000-01-01 +%s years +%s months -1 day' "${datecode:0:2}" "${datecode:2}"
        LC_ALL=C date -d "$thedate" +'%Y %b'
done
```

Output:

```
2019 Aug
2019 Apr
2020 Dec
2020 Jan
2021 Nov
```

Slightly more efficient code which only calls GNU `date` once:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

datecodes=(1908 1904 2012 2001 2111)

for datecode in "${datecodes[@]}"; do
        printf '2000-01-01 +%s years +%s months -1 day\n' "${datecode:0:2}" "${datecode:2}"
done | LC_ALL=C date -f - +'%Y %b'
```

Note that this code allows you to write e.g. `2013 Apr` as the code `1040`.

To get the names of the abbreviated months formatted according te the current locale, and not according to the POSIX locale, remove `LC_ALL=C` in front of the calls to `date`.

---

Working without GNU `date`, using the same approach as you do, with validation of the month part of the date code:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

datecodes=(1908 1904 2012 2001 2111 1040)

declare -A months
months=(
        [01]=Jan [02]=Feb [03]=Mar
        [04]=Apr [05]=May [06]=Jun
        [07]=Jul [08]=Aug [09]=Sep
        [10]=Oct [11]=Nov [12]=Dec
)

for datecode in "${datecodes[@]}"; do
        YY=${datecode:0:2}
        MM=${datecode:2}

        if [ -z "${months[$MM:-empty]}" ]; then
                printf '"%s" is an invalid month\n' "$MM" >&2
                continue
        fi

        printf '20%s %s\n' "$YY" "${months[$MM]}"
done
```

This uses the `months` as an associative array.

Comment: busybox `date` has a more useful API than GNU `date` for this kind of thing: `date -D%y%m -d 1908 +'%Y %b'`

Comment: Note that with `bash` and your last code, you'd get a `months: bad array subscript` error if `$MM` is empty. You may want to replace `${months[$MM]}` with `${months[${MM:-empty}]}` (or switch to a better shell ;-).

Answer (score 3):

Done by below method Added date in the  mentioned input to get desired output

here i have added date "01" to input mentioned to structure into valid input

```
for i in 1908 1904 2012 2111; do date +%Y" "%b -d $i"01"; done
```

output

```
2019 Aug
2019 Apr
2020 Dec
2021 Nov
```